# Having Trouble Optimizing input parameters to MetPy's interpolate_to_grid

Tags: python, metpy

I am using Metpy's *interpolate_to_grid* function to plot contours for US upper air station data.  I have been getting odd results using the "cressman" and "barnes" interpolation methods, as will be seen below. I believe these methods should give better results for upper-air station data than I am getting, so I would like to know how best to use the "cressman" and "barnes" interpolation methods for this kind of problem: upper air station data, rather than model data.  Thank you!

**NOTE:  Updated 12/11/2022 Question Partially Answered  (see below)**

---

**The Problem**

Consider the following inputs, with (x,y) representing station latitudes and longitudes converted using Cartopy's LambertConformal transformation, and instead of actual station data, we use z, representing a *better-behaved* paraboloidal function.

```
x = np.array([-588983.27466878, -597509.66039475, -593548.25150405,
       -708631.9755505 ,  141572.74682356, -255553.18180321,
          2605.75272771, -151524.57820357, -203291.23499391,
        -87463.57692061,  -22995.70471404,  374092.71512281,
        214697.3152085 ,  169183.52087143,  700245.60311235,
        297722.11595698,  258836.14441127,  463635.45150329,
        495809.6650171 ,  941489.32668957, 1187111.28831832,
        945411.2861692 ,  861812.39100534,  535475.69810851,
        508126.79898721,  647449.62111219,  919682.88858901,
       1017240.1399329 , 1172517.98849875])

y = np.array([ -680251.55108761,  -330509.2160825 ,    24118.72712136,
         888634.46530843,  1031366.82096134,  1000957.63129123,
         302813.43368973,    25326.16666977,  -331119.27031642,
        -616634.39369923, -1001199.94104898,   452311.04341359,
          46298.26388061,  -302270.45196599,    -3201.83555954,
        -668399.94426101,  -994537.91752629,  1173948.32332572,
        1513810.0688783 ,  1096427.60089224,   217056.91961851,
         451671.20085842,   665507.85533899,   221907.02519804,
        -494811.23266806,  -512631.01355181,  -248034.64814128,
        -566019.80063491,  -154148.98796047])

# synthetic data describing paraboloid, scaled by 1e-11 to get z into the range [0,25]

z = np.zeros(len(x))
xmean = np.mean(x)
ymean = np.mean(y)
z = 1e-11*((x-xmean)**2 + (y-ymean)**2)

#  This should be symmetric about (roughly) the center of the region of interest
```

Now interpolate that data to a grid using the "barnes" method, allowing the function to select the default *search_radius*.  Also plot the station locations in red.

```
#  Interpolate z to a regular grid using MetPy's interpolate_to_grid
X,Y,Z = interpolate_to_grid(x,y,z,interp_type='barnes',hres=25000)
Levels = np.arange(np.floor(np.nanmin(Z)),np.ceil(np.nanmax(Z)))

fig0 = plt.figure(figsize=(7.5,7.5))
fig0.patch.set_facecolor('white')
fig0.patch.set_alpha(1)
ax0 = fig0.add_subplot(1,1,1)


plt.contour(X,Y,Z,levels=Levels,colors='gray',linewidths=.5)
cf0 = ax0.contour(X,Y,Z,alpha=.75,levels=Levels,colors='gray',linewidths=.5)
ax0.clabel(cf0, cf0.levels, inline = True, fontsize=10, colors='black', fmt='%.0f')
plt.scatter(x,y,s=5,color = 'red')

fig0.savefig('Fig1.png',bbox_inches='tight',dpi=(144))

plt.show()

## OUTPUT  ##
```

[image: Figure 1. Barnes Interpolation of Test Paraboloid]

Clearly this does not represent a paraboloid, although the contours do suggest a minimum in a concave-up surface near the center of the region of interest.  To make sure we are doing things reasonably, try a simpler interpolation function (*cubic*).

```
#  Try a simpler interpolation function
X,Y,Z1 = interpolate_to_grid(x,y,z,interp_type='cubic',hres=25000)
Level1s = np.arange(np.floor(np.nanmin(Z1)),np.ceil(np.nanmax(Z1)))
    
fig0 = plt.figure(figsize=(7.5,7.5))
fig0.patch.set_facecolor('white')
fig0.patch.set_alpha(1)
ax0 = fig0.add_subplot(1,1,1)


cf0 = ax0.contour(X,Y,Z1,alpha=.75,levels=Level1s,colors='gray',linewidths=.5)
ax0.clabel(cf0, cf0.levels, inline = True, fontsize=10, colors='black', fmt='%.0f')
plt.scatter(x,y,s=5,color = 'red')

fig0.savefig('Fig2.png',bbox_inches='tight',dpi=(144))

plt.show()

##  OUTPUT  ##
```

[image: Figure 2. Cubic Interpolation of Test Paraboloid]

This is a lot more like what we expected to see (ignoring the incomplete contours near the edges due to nan's in the interpolated data, which are not an issue at this point.)

We get a similar result using the "linear" method (not shown), although predictably the contours are not as smooth.

Trying the "cressman" method, we do get a more reasonable set of contours, but still not as good as found using the *cubic* and *linear* methods:

```
#  Try the cressman interpolation function
X,Y,Z3 = interpolate_to_grid(x,y,z,interp_type='cressman',hres=25000)
Level3s = np.arange(np.floor(np.nanmin(Z3)),np.ceil(np.nanmax(Z3)))

fig0 = plt.figure(figsize=(7.5,7.5))
fig0.patch.set_facecolor('white')
fig0.patch.set_alpha(1)
ax0 = fig0.add_subplot(1,1,1)

cf0 = ax0.contour(X,Y,Z3,alpha=.75,levels=Level3s,colors='gray',linewidths=.5)
ax0.clabel(cf0, cf0.levels, inline = True, fontsize=10, colors='black', fmt='%.0f')
plt.scatter(x,y,s=5,color = 'red')

fig0.savefig('Fig3.png',bbox_inches='tight',dpi=(144))

plt.show()

##  OUTPUT  ##
```

[image: Figure 3. Cressman Interpolation of Test Paraboloid]

The *cressman* method does provide a better representation of the test paraboloid, but the overall scale is wrong:  the minimum of the cressman-based surface is ~5 (compared to 0 for the test surface), and a maximum ~13 (compared to ~20 for the test surface.)  Also, the cressman-minimum is too broad and not centered on the region of interest.

Finally:  adding *search_radius* as a parameter (for the *cressman* and *barnes* methods), and increasing the *search_radius* stepwise to 2000000 did not resolve the issues we see above.  Note, however, that values above 1250000 led to increasingly bad performance.  (For brevity, these results are not shown.)

---

**Update 12/11/2022. Question Partially Answered**

After experimenting with the additional barnes-related input parameters *gamma* and *kappa_star*, we are getting more reasonable results.

```
#  Interpolate z to a regular grid using MetPy's interpolate_to_grid, adding gamma and kappa_star parameters:
X,Y,Z = interpolate_to_grid(x,y,z,interp_type='barnes',hres=100000,gamma=5,kappa_star=1)
Levels = np.arange(np.floor(np.nanmin(Z)),np.ceil(np.nanmax(Z)))

fig0 = plt.figure(figsize=(7.5,7.5))
fig0.patch.set_facecolor('white')
fig0.patch.set_alpha(1)
ax0 = fig0.add_subplot(1,1,1)


plt.contour(X,Y,Z,levels=Levels,colors='gray',linewidths=.5)
cf0 = ax0.contour(X,Y,Z,alpha=.75,levels=Levels,colors='gray',linewidths=.5)
ax0.clabel(cf0, cf0.levels, inline = True, fontsize=8, colors='gray', fmt='%.0f')
plt.scatter(x,y,s=5,color = 'red')

for i in np.arange(len(z)):
    plt.text(x[i],y[i],np.round(z[i],1),fontsize=10)

    
fig0.savefig('Fig4.png',bbox_inches='tight',dpi=(144))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After further experimentation, it seems that some of my difficulties in optimizing Barnes interpolation are related to a misunderstanding of how the Barnes algorithm is applied in MetPy's *interpolate_to_grid*:

1. The function applies a single-pass Barnes interpolation (this has since been confirmed off-list by a MetPy developer.)
2. In the Koch et. al. 1983 paper ("An interactive Barnes objective map analysis scheme for use with satellite and conventional data"), the parameter *gamma* is used to scale *kappa* in the second interpolation pass, which raises the question of how *gamma* is used in *interpolate_to_grid*.
3. It can be demonstrated that the output of *interpolate_to_grid* depends, not on *kappa_star* and *gamma* individually, but on their product.  This can be confirmed by inspecting the outputs of the function with various values of *kappa_star* and *gamma* while keeping their product constant.

```
# Confirm That the output of interpolate_to_grid() only depends on the
#  product of kappa_star and gamma

import numpy as np
from metpy.interpolate import interpolate_to_grid
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([-588983.27466878, -597509.66039475, -593548.25150405,
       -708631.9755505 ,  141572.74682356, -255553.18180321,
          2605.75272771, -151524.57820357, -203291.23499391,
        -87463.57692061,  -22995.70471404,  374092.71512281,
        214697.3152085 ,  169183.52087143,  700245.60311235,
        297722.11595698,  258836.14441127,  463635.45150329,
        495809.6650171 ,  941489.32668957, 1187111.28831832,
        945411.2861692 ,  861812.39100534,  535475.69810851,
        508126.79898721,  647449.62111219,  919682.88858901,
       1017240.1399329 , 1172517.98849875])

y = np.array([ -680251.55108761,  -330509.2160825 ,    24118.72712136,
         888634.46530843,  1031366.82096134,  1000957.63129123,
         302813.43368973,    25326.16666977,  -331119.27031642,
        -616634.39369923, -1001199.94104898,   452311.04341359,
          46298.26388061,  -302270.45196599,    -3201.83555954,
        -668399.94426101,  -994537.91752629,  1173948.32332572,
        1513810.0688783 ,  1096427.60089224,   217056.91961851,
         451671.20085842,   665507.85533899,   221907.02519804,
        -494811.23266806,  -512631.01355181,  -248034.64814128,
        -566019.80063491,  -154148.98796047])

# synthetic data describing paraboloid, scaled by 1e-11 to get z into the range [0,25]

z = np.zeros(len(x))
xmean = np.mean(x)
ymean = np.mean(y)
z = 1e-11*((x-xmean)**2 + (y-ymean)**2)

# Vary kappa_star and gamma according to:  kappa_star * gamma = 5.052
X, Y, Z = interpolate_to_grid(x, y, z, interp_type='barnes',hres=50000,kappa_star=5.052,gamma=1)
X, Y, Z1 = interpolate_to_grid(x, y, z, interp_type='barnes',hres=50000,kappa_star=10.104,gamma=.5)

Levels = np.arange(np.floor(np.nanmin(Z)),np.ceil(np.nanmax(Z)))
Levels1 = np.arange(np.floor(np.nanmin(Z1)),np.ceil(np.nanmax(Z1)))

fig0 = plt.figure(figsize=(7.5,7.5))
fig0.patch.set_facecolor('white')
fig0.patch.set_alpha(1)
ax0 = fig0.add_subplot(1,1,1)


cf0 = ax0.contour(X,Y,Z,alpha=.75,levels=Levels,colors='gray',linewidths=.5)
ax0.clabel(cf0, cf0.levels, inline = True, fontsize=10, colors='gray', fmt='%.0f')
cf1 = ax0.contour(X,Y,Z1,alpha=.75,levels=Levels1,colors='red',linewidths=1,linestyles='dotted')
ax0.clabel(cf1, cf1.levels, inline = True, fontsize=10, colors='red', fmt='%.0f')
plt.scatter(x,y,s=5,color = 'red')

fig0.savefig('Fig1a.png',bbox_inches='tight',dpi=(144))

plt.show()
```

The output follows, and although it is fairly clear the two outputs are identical, checking the mean-squared difference between the two outputs Z and Z1 yields zero.  Therefore one only needs to vary either *gamma* or *kappa_star*, and without this understanding how they interact it may be hard to optimize the output.

[image: Check kappa_star*gamma=constant gives no difference]

**CONCLUSION**

MetPy's *interpolate_to_grid* function performs a Single-Pass Barnes Interpolation in which *kappa_star* and *gamma* are related to the first-pass parameter kappa (Koch, 1983) as follows:

```
                  kappa = kappa_star * gamma.
```

Therefore, one can use the default value of one (*kappa_star* or *gamma*) and vary the other to optimize the interpolation output.